# Partitioning hard drive from Windows XP-SP3 installation manager

Tags: windows-xp, installation, partitioning, truecrypt

Planning to do a fresh install of Windows XP-SP3 and normally I just delete the current partition via the installation manager and create a new partition, but I just started using a TrueCrypt container and would like to switch to having a partition for the Windows XP-SP3 installation (which I'll reformat on build) and a partition for the TrueCrypt container (which I'll just mount as a drive after the OS is built).

What do I need to do from the installation manager to create the partition for the OS and TrueCrypt container -- and once the OS is built, what do I need to do to mount/format the partition for the TrueCrypt container?

Possible there's a better way to do this, but one requirement is that I be able to backup the TrueCrypt data on a external hard-drive, and that I'm able to mount the backup from a TrueCrypt manager without having to anything other than install the TrueCrypt manager and point it at the data. Also, just to be clear, my plan is to create the partitions, then the OS, then format the partition for the TrueCrypt data; then at that point, the next time I rebuild the partition for the OS, just leave the partition for the TrueCrypt data alone, reformat the partition for the OS, then mount the TrueCrypt data partition after the OS is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want to create a partition where one or more partitions already exist, you must first delete the existing partition or partitions, and then create the new partition. You can press D to delete an existing partition, and then press L (or press ENTER, and then press L if it is the System partition) to confirm that you want to delete the partition. Repeat this step for each existing partition that you want to include in the new partition. **When all the partitions are deleted, select the remaining non-partitioned space, and then press C to create the new partition.
>   To create the partition with the maximum size, press ENTER. To specify the partition size, type the size in megabytes (MB) for the new partition, and then press ENTER.**
>   If you want to create additional partitions, repeat steps g. and h.
>   To format the partition and install Windows XP, go to step 2.
>
> If you do not want to install Windows XP, press F3 two times to exit the Windows Setup program, and then do not follow the remaining steps in this article.
>
> To format the partition without installing Windows XP, use a different utility.
>
> Step 2: Format the hard disk and install Windows XP
>   Use the ARROW keys to select the partition where you want to install Windows XP, and then press ENTER.
>
> Select the format option that you want to use to format the partition. You can select from the following options:
>
> Format the partition by using the NTFS file system (Quick)
>
> Format the partition by using the FAT file system (Quick)
>
> Format the partition by using the NTFS file system
>
> Format the partition by using the FAT file system
>
> Leave the current file system intact (no changes)
>
> Notes:
>   If the selected partition is a new partition, the option to leave the current file system intact is not available.
>   If the selected partition is larger than 32 gigabytes (GB), the FAT file system option is not available.
>   If the selected partition is larger than 2 GB, the Windows Setup program uses the FAT32 file system (you must press ENTER to confirm).
>   If the partition is smaller than 2 GB, the Windows Setup program uses the FAT16 file system.
>   If you deleted and created a new System partition, but you are installing Windows XP on a different partition, you are prompted to select a file system for both the System and Startup partitions.
>   Press ENTER.
>
> After the Windows Setup program formats the partition, follow the instructions that appear on the screen to install Windows XP. After the Windows Setup program is finished and you have restarted the computer, you can use the Disk Management tools in Windows XP to create or format more partitions. For additional information about how to use the Windows XP Disk Management tools to partition and format your hard disk, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309000

.

[Source of Information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313348)